# How to remove EGR valve that’s baked on 2012 Holden Cruze

Tags: gasket, stuck-bolt, egr, cruze

I have a 2012 Holden/Chevrolet Cruze (2.0L turbo diesel) with a stuck EGR valve. I was pleasantly surprised to find that the EGR valve is on the top of the engine and reasonably easy to access, however after undoing the three hex bolts, the thing is still stuck fast!

I’ve tried multiple heating and cooling cycles after spraying a lot of penetrant around the seam where it should come apart, and used a wrench to try and get leverage, but the most movement I’ve gotten is a sound of escaping pressure/vacuum for a second if attempting shortly after shutting off the engine. It doesn’t visibly budge at all.

Does anyone have further tips for getting this removed? I’m worried about adding further leverage as the only thing I can brace against is the intake manifold itself which I’ve already marked with the wrench.

I was able to take the actuator off of it fairly easily and there was heaps of carbon built up under it too, but I really need to clean/replace the valve itself.

Comment: Are you completely replacing it? As in, is the housing and everything going on it? If so, just give it a good hit with a hammer ... should pop off with a little bit of force. Old saying goes, *If at first you don't succeed, get a bigger hammer. If it breaks, it needed replaced anways.*

Comment: Unfortunately it’s down under some vacuum, coolant, and fuel lines that make it difficult to get a good strike on it.

Comment: In fact, I’ve used an old wrench to transfer the strike of the hammer to the EGR valve and all I’ve managed to do is put sizeable dents in the body of the valve without it budging. If I spray penetrant down the holes where the bolts came out I can see it leak out the seam so I’m completely lost as to how this thing is stuck so fast.

Comment: Can you add a photo?